# BeautifulSoup - extract <a> value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to extract all values like "`Dance`" in the format below:

```
 <a href="http://earmilk.com/category/dance/" 
     class="tiptipBlog genre-dance" 
     title="View all posts in Dance" 
     rel="tag">Dance</a>
```

I've tried:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', rel=True):
    tag = a["rel"]
```

which partially works, printing `[u'tag']`. but then if I go on:

```
    print [t.string for t in tag]
```

I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'string'`

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `get_text()`

`soup.find("a").get_text()`

would give you u'Dance'

For list of links

```
all_links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in all_links:
    print link.get_text()
```